# Auto incrementing build number for appxbundle package when deploying to appcenter via vsts

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I [know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/windows/uwp/first-build#34-increment-version-number) that appcenter build process is capable to increment build numbers when creating appxbundle packages. However I build packages via vsts service and then deploy packages to appcenter for further testing.

How can I get the same functionality on vsts side? I need somehow increment build numbers for packages get deployed to appcenter [image: appcenter deploy via vsts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the version through PowerShell (add PowerShell task to build definition), the sample scripts: UpdateVersion.ps1

> ```
> #Based on https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/scripts/index
> # Enable -Verbose option
> [CmdletBinding()] 
>
> $VersionRegex = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
>
> $ManifestVersionRegex = " Version=""\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"""
>
> if (-not $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)
> {
>     Write-Error ("BUILD_BUILDNUMBER environment variable is missing.")
>     exit 1
> }
> Write-Verbose "BUILD_BUILDNUMBER: $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER"
>
> $ScriptPath = $null
> try
> {
>     $ScriptPath = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value.MyCommand.Path
>     $ScriptDir = Split-Path -Parent $ScriptPath
> }
> catch {}
>
> if (!$ScriptPath)
> {
>     Write-Error "Current path not found!"
>     exit 1
> }
>
> # Get and validate the version data
> $VersionData = [regex]::matches($Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER,$VersionRegex)
> switch($VersionData.Count)
> {
>    0        
>       { 
>          Write-Error "Could not find version number data in BUILD_BUILDNUMBER."
>          exit 1
>       }
>    1 {}
>    default 
>       { 
>          Write-Warning "Found more than instance of version data in BUILD_BUILDNUMBER." 
>          Write-Warning "Will assume first instance is version."
>       }
> }
> $NewVersion = $VersionData[0]
> Write-Verbose "Version: $NewVersion"
>
>
> $AssemblyVersion = $NewVersion
> $ManifestVersion = " Version=""$NewVersion"""
>
> Write-Host "Version: $AssemblyVersion"
> Write-Host "Manifest: $ManifestVersion"
> Write-Host "ScriptDir: " $ScriptDir
>
> # Apply the version to the assembly property files
> $assemblyInfoFiles = gci $ScriptDir -recurse -include "*Properties*","My Project" | 
>     ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | 
>     foreach { gci -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -include AssemblyInfo.* }
>
> if($assemblyInfoFiles)
> {
>     Write-Host "Will apply $AssemblyVersion to $($assemblyInfoFiles.count) Assembly Info Files."
>
>     foreach ($file in $assemblyInfoFiles) {
>         $filecontent = Get-Content($file)
>         attrib $file -r
>         $filecontent -replace $VersionRegex, $AssemblyVersion | Out-File $file utf8
>
>         Write-Host "$file.FullName - version applied"
>     }
> }
> else
> {
>     Write-Warning "No Assembly Info Files found."
> }
>
> # Try Manifests
> $manifestFiles = gci .\ -recurse -include "Package.appxmanifest" 
>
> if($manifestFiles)
> {
>     Write-Host "Will apply $ManifestVersion to $($manifestFiles.count) Manifests."
>
>     foreach ($file in $manifestFiles) {
>         $filecontent = Get-Content($file)
>         attrib $file -r
>         $filecontent -replace $ManifestVersionRegex, $ManifestVersion | Out-File $file utf8
>
>         Write-Host "$file.FullName - version applied to Manifest"
>     }
> }
> else
> {
>     Write-Warning "No Manifest files found."
> }
>
> Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppxVersion;]$NewVersion")
> ```

More information, you can refer to this article: [Set up a continuous deployment build for sideloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#set-up-a-continuous-deployment-build-for-sideloading)

Comment: Hi! starian-chen-msft! Thanks! How can I invoke poweshell script through my build process. As I can see I somehow have to add targets here - https://github.com/melezhik/uwp-example/blob/master/C%23/CSHelloWorldUniversalApp/CSHelloWorldUniversalApp.csproj ?

Comment: Just click + and select PowerShell task.

Comment: That's ok. Now when I have my artifact file name having a build number, how can I "instruct" release definition to pick those? As you might have noticed my  release definition is set to CSHelloWorldUniversalApp_2.0.0.1_x86_x64_ARM_bundle.appxupload path, which does not work for dynamically set build numbers ...

Comment: You can get the build number through `$(Build.BuildNumber)` or `$(Release.Artifacts.{Artifact alias}.BuildNumber)` in release.

Comment: so CSHelloWorldUniversalApp_2.0.$(Build.BuildNumber).1_x86_x64_ARM_bundle.appxupload , did a trick.Thank you for support!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165206/discussion-between-alexey-melezhik-and-starian-chen-msft).