# Increment Build & Version Number of Android App using Azure DevOps & App Centre

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I am using Azure DevOps and AppCenter(Distribution) for implementing my CICD. Based on the steps mentioned below I have implemented the both CI & CD tasks.

Thant means,

I will create the build using Azure Devops (VSTS) & Push that in to App Centre.

[Steps I Follow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/vsts-deploy)

Here my doubt is,

How I can increment my Build and Version numbers while distributing these builds?
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easy way is to install [Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks) extension for Azure DevOps. You get a task "Bump Version" (for Andriod and iOS).

The task change app's version name and code at build time.

**Inputs:**

`sourcePath` -  Path to android manifest

`versionCode` - code number that must be an integer (put the build number variable, it's incremented automatically)

`versionCodeOffset` - a specific number to increment the version code

`versionName`- user visible name

`printFile` - output the file before and after changing variables

Another option is to install [Colin's ALM Corner Build & Release Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks) extension and use the `Version Assemblies` task following [this](https://montemagno.com/version-bumping-ios-and-android-apps-in-visual-studio-te/) detailed tutorial.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341790/how-can-i-associate-the-build-version-generated-by-vsts-to-a-release-in-vs-app-c) question & answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an alternative method, try modifying either the version number, version name or both in the module build.gradle file like below:

```
 android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.sample.testapp'
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.2"
    }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do almost anything with shell scripting, but I figured out to Automate Build numbering & App versioning for Android WITHOUT shell scripting while using Microsoft AppCenter CI/CD pipelines!
You can create 2 environment variables `VERSION_CODE` & `VERSION_NAME` and then use them in the build.gradle file like this:

```
versionCode System.getenv("VERSION_CODE") ? System.getenv("VERSION_CODE").toInteger() : 201
versionName System.getenv("VERSION_NAME") ? System.getenv("VERSION_NAME").toString() : "1.2.1"
```

[More details in this article](https://dev.to/saamerm/android-version-code-name-from-appcenter-environment-variables-2a3a)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you don't want to install an extra plugin in Azure) is using the embedded [counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) function.

So basically you'll need to create the variable in the root of your pipeline, smth. like this:
`versionCode: $[counter('Google_Play_version_offset', 100)]` 
Then it will autoincrement for each build - 100, 101, 102, etc.

In the gradle task you can pass this value with next:

```
- task: Gradle@2
      inputs:
        ...
        options: '-PversionCode=$(versionCode)'
        ...
```

Please also make sure to handle this option in the `build.gradle` file.